# Добавить пункт в контекстное меню

Tags: java, android, android-ui

Возможно этот вопрос уже задавался, но я его так и не нашел. Как добавить пункт в "глобальное" контекстное меню. То что вызывается во всех приложениях при выделении текста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту статью: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999

Comment: @YungBlade, поставьте как ответ на вопрос пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте следующий intent-filter в свой файл android-manifest.xml:

```
<activity
   android:name=".ProcessTextActivity"
   android:label="@string/process_text_action_name">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Получите выделенный юзером текст в активности вашего приложения в методе onCreate():

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.process_text_main);
    CharSequence text = getIntent()
      .getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT);
    // получение текста
}
```

Больше информации в [статье на medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999).